# Issue with simple query in cakePhp

Tags: cakephp, controller

I'm learning CakePhp, and I still lock on this issue, probably really easy.
I just want to increment a value (count) in my DB.

I generated the code via bake, all works fine, but I want to tune it to make a complete app.

another question, is it better to do it in the controller or in a model ? I'm a bit confuse with it

in StockController.php:

```
public function increment($id = null){
        $this->Stock->updateAll(
            array('Stock.count' => 'Stock.count + 1'),
            array('Stock.id' => $id ));
        $this->Flash->success(__('stock count +1.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

I got a 500 error message

Comment: Please enable the debug mode and update the question with the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP you have two kinds of Model objects:

- [Table Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/table-objects.html) - provide access to the collection of entities stored in a specific table
- [Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html) - one single row from a Table Object

For your StockController `$this->Stock` seems to be your Table Object. To change (or increment) a single Entity you need to get this Entity first and then save it:

```
public function increment ($id = null) {
    // Get Entity + increment count
    $entity = $this->Stock->get($id);
    $entity->count = $entity->count++;

    // Then you need to save your Entity using the Table Object
    if ($this->Stock->save($entity)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('Stock count +1.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    // If save fails
    $this->Flash->error(__('Stock increment failed :('));
}
```

Small changes of your data I would do in a Controller, if you have to update and modify more complex data I would create [Setters](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators) on your Entity or methods in you Table Object.

Happy coding!

Comment: It should be noted that this method isn't transaction-safe!

Comment: really thanks for the solution + explanation, just a note :
$entity->count = $entity->count+1; (because ++ doesn't work)